# Opensuse 11.0 Memory error

Tags: opensuse

I am using OpenSuse 11.0. The system got hung and i have to do hard reboot.After investigating the logs i got following error:-

```
Mem-info:
 kernel: Node 0 DMA per-cpu:
 kernel: CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
kernel: Node 0 DMA32 per-cpu:
 kernel: CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 174
 kernel: Active:229577 inactive:546 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0
 kernel:  free:1982 slab:5674 mapped:18 pagetables:10359 bounce:0
 kernel: Node 0 DMA free:4000kB min:32kB low:40kB high:48kB active:2800kB inactive:2184kB present:8860kB pages_scanned:9859 all_unreclaimable? yes
 kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 994 994 994
 kernel: Node 0 DMA32 free:3928kB min:4016kB low:5020kB high:6024kB active:915508kB inactive:0kB present:1018016kB pages_scanned:2233186 all_unreclaimable? yes
 lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
 Node 0 DMA: 0*4kB 8*8kB 6*16kB 2*32kB 3*64kB 6*128kB 1*256kB 1*512kB 0*1024kB 1*2048kB 0*4096kB = 4000kB
Node 0 DMA32: 4*4kB 9*8kB 0*16kB 4*32kB 2*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 1*512kB 1*1024kB 1*2048kB 0*4096kB = 3928kB
 19418 total pagecache pages
 Swap cache: add 36342342, delete 36342340, find 14356263/18138459
 Free swap  = 0kB
 Total swap = 771080kB
 Free swap:            0kB
 262144 pages of RAM
 kernel: 5430 reserved pages
```

It is something related to memory leakage but not sure.

If anybody is having solution of similar issue please let me know..

Thanks in advance

Rajiv

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing something like running "while true ; do sleep 10 ; ps auxw >> ~/processes ; done". Then you can probably spot the memory hog that chewed through 700 megs of swap after your system comes back up by reading through the file and spotting the growing program.

When you find the program that is eating all your memory, you can use rlimits (man bash, search for 'ulimit') to limit how much memory that program uses before you start it, and maybe keep your system a little more sane.